# Как нажать на кнопку reCaptcha checker на python/selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, recaptcha

Мне нужно нажать на данную кнопку активации reCaptcha:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И я не знаю как мне это можно сделать, пытался через full xPath, но оно просто не нажимает на нее. Использую Selenium последней версии.

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что recaptcha находится не на самой странице, а в `iframe`, что по сути является окном в другую страницу, встроенную на данную страницу.

В selenium вы можете попробовать переключиться в iframe и работать с её содержимым вот так:

```py
# Находим iframe
iframe = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#modal > iframe") # Вставьте здесь свой селектор для тега iframe с капчей.

# Переключаем внимание драйвера на нужный iframe
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

# Теперь мы можем нажимать на Капчу. (Селектор лишь для примера, вам нужно подобрать свой)
driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'button').click()
```

Но сразу хочу заметить, что скорее всего данный способ вам не поможет. Капча для того и придумана, чтобы защищаться от вот таких автоматических способов взаимодействия с сайтом. Так что скорее всего, когда вы нажмете на кнопку, вам покажут картинки, или попросят какие-то ещё дополнительные подтверждения, что вы человек. Более простой способ обойти такую капчу - использовать специализированные расширения для браузеров или сервисы типа `2Captcha`.

Я попробую показать, как я обходил капчу в одном из проектов:

На сервисе [anti-captcha](https://anti-captcha.com/ru) зарегистрировался и оплатил. (там вроде есть бесплатные тестовые 20 прохождений). Скачал [их расширение](https://antcpt.com/eng/download/google-chrome-options.html) и установил в браузере.

В настройках указал автоматический запуск решения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь капча автоматически решается, если она есть на странице. (занимает примерно 3-8 секунд, поставьте задержку.)

Только есть проблема: при запуске браузера через selenium все расширения отключаются. Как это решить?

Я делал так: поставил расширение внутри браузера под своим обычным пользователем (просто запустив браузер как обычно). А при запуске selenium'a указал профиль, с которым нужно запустить браузер. На примере оперы: Зашел `menu->help->Paths-> profile`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И при инициализации selenium указал то, что мне нужно:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
BROWSER_PROFILE = r"/home/artur1214/.config/opera"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('user-data-dir=' + BROWSER_PROFILE)
driver = webdriver.Opera(
    executable_path=r"ПУТЬ ДО ИСПОЛНЯЕМОГО ФАЙЛА БРАУЗЕРА",
    options=options)
```

Таким образом при запуске у меня сохранятся настройки профиля, в том числе и расширения. Теперь при открытии нужной страницы капча автоматически решится спустя ~5-8 секунд после загрузки. При этом не нужно ничего нажимать или искать

Comment: Да, ваш ответ неплохой, но мне это не нужно, что-бы я ждал 7-8 секунд, а мне нужен именно моментальный отклик на кнопку reCaptcha, поэтому для этого и использую Selenium

Answer (score 0):

Зачем усложнять? Можно обойтись нажатием клавиши "ENTER" (если курсор далеко, то юзаем "TAB", "UP"/"DOWN"(таб и стрелочки)).
В Selenium для этого есть функции